# How to call restful service in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

This is my sharepoint service code to get list of my documents.

```
var docuList;
function getList(){
            var context = new SP.ClientContext('/');
            var oColl = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test');
            var Query = new SP.CamlQuery();

            Query.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Created\" Ascending=\"FALSE\" /></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\" /><FieldRef Name=\"FileRef\" /></ViewFields></View>");
            docuList = oColl.getItems(Query);

            context.load(docuList);
            context.executeQueryAsync(successCall, failCall);
    }

function successCall(res,arg){
        var litToIter = docuList.getEnumerator();
        while (litToIter.moveNext()) {
            var item = litToIter.get_current();
             var DocUrl = item.get_item("FileRef");
             console.log(DocUrl);  // My list of documents which I added 
        }   
    }
```

When I execute this code I am getting my list. But If I use rest service to get a list, am not getting my list of data(Getting some different data in XMl format). I tried Rest call in postman. This is my Restful service URL to get list of documents.

http://MysiteURL/site/_api/lists/getbytitle('Test')

Am not sure whether this is a  correct way to hit share point, can someone correct my URL or guide me how to get my list by Rest service.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This REST request will get you all lists available in your site. 
http://myserver/_vti_bin/ListData.svc

for more information about calling SharePoint RESTful service, please refer to this MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff521587%28v=office.14%29.aspx)